# How initialize array of classes?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this class constructor:

```
Pairs (int Pos, char *Pre, char *Post, bool Attach = true);
```

How can I initialize array of Pairs classes? I tried:

```
Pairs Holder[3] =
{
    {Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post"},
    {Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post"},
    {Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post"}
};
```

Apparently it's not working, I also tried to use () brackets instead of {} but compiler keeps moaning all the time. Sorry if it is lame question, I googled quite hard but wasn't able to find answer :/

Comment: You will usually get faster and better replies when posting the error messages from the compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call the constructor explicitly:

```
Pairs Holder[3] =
{
    Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post"),
    Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post"),
    Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post")
};
```

Comment: I don't understand the syntax. I thought you can't call the constructor explicitly (it is implicitly called when an object is instantiated). Additionally, it does not return anything.

Answer (score 6):

Call the constructor:

```
Pairs Holder[3] =
{
    Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post"),
    Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post"),
    Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post")
};
```

This is similar to saying

```
Holder[0] = Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post");
Holder[1] = Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post");
Holder[2] = Pairs(Input.find("as"), "Pre", "Post");
```

A full-fledged class can be found [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0180__Class/Initializeanarrayofobjectsbyreferencingtheconstructordirectly.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the link, tutorial there seems to be interesting, I'll give it a go. I started to believe I have some error within my code when your first (unedited) comment caused compiler errors as well. Luckily this wasn't the case, thanks for editing.